# Cannot Create Lookup Relationship on Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, lookup, custom-field, relationships, master-detail

I'm trying to create a lookup relationship field however it's giving me an error saying it cannot create a Master-Detail relationship, which is not what I selected. Is there any reasion for this occurring?

[image: error code]

Comment: Did you say `Lookup` - `Required`? that could cause the same

Comment: I did check required, is there no way of making it a requirement to fill in that field without making it a master-detail relationship?

Comment: The problem is not Master-Detail, the problem is that since you are making it required AND you have data in this sObject, SF does not know how to handle this. It cant put no value for existing records as you said it is required and it can’t figure out what value to put there since it’s a lookup.